# WebGL - wait for texture to load

Tags: html, textures, webgl

How do I test if the `WebGLTexture` object is 'complete' ?

Currently I get this message:
`[WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'`

I get this warning because the render-loop is trying to use the texture before its image has finished loading, so how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I've been living with these console messages in my experiments for a while. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way to fix that is to make a 1x1 texture at creation time.

```
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255])); // red
```

Then when the image loads you can replace the 1x1 pixel texture with the image. No flags needed and your scene will render with the color of your choice until the image has loaded.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://someplace/someimage.jpg";
img.onload = function() {
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

   // then either generate mips if the image uses power-of-2 dimensions or 
   // set the filtering correctly for non-power-of-2 images.
   setupTextureFilteringAndMips(img.width, img.height);
}
```

Just for the sake of saving people the trouble of running into the next problem they are most likely going to run into, WebGL requires mips or it requires filtering that doesn't require mips. On top of that it requires textures with dimensions that are a power of 2 (ie, 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 256, 512, etc) to use mips. So, when loading an image you'll most likely want to setup the filtering to handle this correctly.

```
function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
};

function setupTextureFilteringAndMips(width, height) {
  if (isPowerOf2(width) && isPowerOf2(height) {
    // the dimensions are power of 2 so generate mips and turn on 
    // tri-linear filtering.
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
  } else {
    // at least one of the dimensions is not a power of 2 so set the filtering
    // so WebGL will render it.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice trick, get rid of warnings without adding a test/boolean. Question remains that what happens if for some reason the texture is not considered 'complete' for some reason. Is returning from texImage2D sufficient condition to have a 'complete' texture?

Comment: My bad. The value of the 1 pixel one pixel texture should be `[255, 0, 0, 255]` for red. Fixed it above. As for texture complete I'll update the answer

Comment: What a feat! That's stopped days of searching... But - I wanted to use transparent black ([0,0,0,0]), which is not working, probably because I am still getting "WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: texImage2D: invalid texture type" in Chrome 31.0. I'm sure I passed gl.TEXTURE_2D - still looking for the cause

Answer (score 1):

To fix that issue, use some boolean value to tell if the image has loaded.

```
var loaded = false,
    texture,
    img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    // . . . 
    loaded = true;
};
img.src = "path/myimage.jpg";

// render-loop
function render() {
    if(loaded) {
        // use texture
    }
    else {
        // not loaded yet
    }
}
```

Comment: Managing my own boolean would just tell me if the set of APIs, such as texImage2D, have been called. But it won't tell if it succeeded in creating a 'complete' texture? Tracking the booleans separately can be a pain, so instead I modified this to store the boolean inside the WebGL texture object -> texture.isLoaded=false;

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when attempting to deploy my HTML5/JS app to an Android phone using Cordova.

At first, I thought my issue was that my spritesheet/texture atlas was too large for the mobile GPU to load. So I [batch shrank all the images using ImageMagick's `mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) (`mogrify -resize 256x256 *.png`), but was still having issues. This step was still necessary tho (as my `8000x8000 .png` was too much for phones).

Then I used `console.log(`[`navigator.userAgent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)`)` to check my browser version and saw that the Chromium used was older than my browser. So I re-installed the [Crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) and everything is rendering fine.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```