# check if webgl texture is loaded in fragment shader

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

i am writing a webgl program with texturing.

As long as the image isn´t loaded, the texture2D-function returns a vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). So all objects are black.

So i would like to check, if my sampler2D is available.

I have already tried:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    vec4 color = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    if(color.r == 0.0 && color.g == 0.0 && color.b == 0.0)
       color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>
```

But of course this doesn´t make sense, because the texture could be black.

Can anybody help me? How can I check, whether my texture image is already loaded in the fragment shader?

Comment: you cant and you shouldn't, either don't draw or bind a placeholder texture(like 1x1 white) until your texture(s) are loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really check that in WebGL.

Solutions:

1. Don't render until the texture is loaded
2. Use a 1x1 pixel texture to start, fill it in with the image
   once it's loaded. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19748905/128511)
3. Pass in more info to the shader like `uniform bool textureLoaded`.
   Me, I always pick #2 because it means the app runs immediately and the textures get filled in as they download.

Answer (score 1):

I'd provide new uniform which will store data whether texture is loaded or not.

Or you can write 2 shaders with/without texture and select proper one before rendering.